# PHP Accessing parent class function variables

Tags: php

```
class A
{
    public function child1()
    {
        $var1 = 'abc';
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function child1()
    {
        echo parent::$var1; // Return error undefined class constant 'var1'
    }
}
```

How can i access $var1 in this situation ?
Expected result: 'abc'

Comment: You can't, that variable is local to the function, you'd have to make it a class property. Here's the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for object basics.

Answer (score 1):

First you cannot do `class B extends class A`. The correct syntax would be `class B extends A`:

```
class A
{
    public function child1()
    {
        $var1 = 'abc';
        return $var1;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function child1()
    {
        echo parent::child1(); 
    }
}

$temp = new B;
$temp->child1();
```

Now what I've done is return the `$var1` in your `class A`.

You cannot call `echo parent::$var1;` because it is inside a function, so you call the parent function `echo parent::child1();`.

[working example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56e3da31b2da29b931dae1e41e57c5139e5465c2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make $var1 a class property. See following code:

```
<?php
    class A
    {
        protected $var1;
        public function child1()
        {
            $this->var1 = 'abc';
        }
    }

    class B extends A
    {
        public function child1()
        {
            parent::child1();
            echo $this->var1;
        }
    }
$b = new B();
$b->child1();    
?>
```